# What is the function of this Merlin engine's tube, and why is it getting red hot?

Tags: spacex, falcon-9, engine-design, identify-this-object, merlin-1d

In [the video of the recent SpaceX Starlink launch](https://youtu.be/riBaVeDTEWI), one view of the Falcon-9 2nd stage engine shows a cane-shaped tube that glows red hot at the "handle" end and seems to get hotter over time.

**Question:** What is the function of this tube, and why is it getting red hot?

The first two images are from `T+04:19` and  `T+07:38`, you can see here and in the video that as the tube heats up the red glow moves from the "handle" of the cane only and starts down the body.

The next two views are different lighting from the Sun to better understand the tubing and geometry.

[image: Falcon-9 engine with parts glowing red-hot] [image: Falcon-9 engine with parts glowing red-hot]

[image: Falcon-9 engine sunlit]  [image: Falcon-9 engine sunlit]

Comment: That rams-horn shaped thing is almost certainly where the drive gas exits from the turbine. The J-shaped tube seems kinda small, so it's probably ignition system related or a feedline for the gas generator.  All guesses, of course.  There's a side view in this answer: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25925/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble to me all engines look like some version of this: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30598/12102 similar to what car engines looked like after all the emissions control tubes, wires, sensors, valves and gizmos were added.

Comment: I could answer the red hot part: *because it's connected to a running rocket engine* :)  Of course there are other parts that aren't red hot.

Comment: [This picture](https://tinyurl.com/y4cahohl) seems like it has some explanation on it but because of company proxy I'm unable to open it in full resolution.
For my understanding are those the same long bendy pipes as on [this picture](https://tinyurl.com/y3vwljt2)?

Comment: @GittingGud I'm not comfortable with tiny urls. Can you show the real links to the sites you are looking at? Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh The picture with the annotaions: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fi.warosu.org%2Fdata%2Fsci%2Fimg%2F0092%2F49%2F1508963477331.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwarosu.org%2Fsci%2Fthread%2F9249438&docid=b4oRpavmcGukoM&tbnid=CUNcIDa7vmzctM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjnw7Pgzb3iAhWoShUIHTTxCJ0QMwiUASgqMCo..i&w=7569&h=1616&client=firefox-b-d&bih=928&biw=1363&q=merlin%201d&ved=0ahUKEwjnw7Pgzb3iAhWoShUIHTTxCJ0QMwiUASgqMCo&iact=mrc&uact=8
High Res picture of Merlin 1C: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/SpaceX_Merlin_1c_4928541992_9ea1d90be4_o.jpg

Comment: @GittingGud 2nd image found here: [1](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Merlin_(rocket_engine)) , [2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:SpaceX_Merlin_1c_4928541992_9ea1d90be4_o.jpg), [3](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-a-turbopump-for-liquids-like-water-and-a-rocket-engine-turbopump) yes it does look similar, thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Those pipes are definitely some kind of fuel return line, maybe from the regenerative cooling loop?

Comment: @GittingGud **red hot** fuel return?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94192/discussion-between-gittinggud-and-uhoh).

Comment: it's real red glow, not IR leaking through filters since it doesn't look weird/purple color:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uPPw.png from Quora [Sensors: Why does infrared appear purple in digital cameras?](https://www.quora.com/Sensors-Why-does-infrared-appear-purple-in-digital-cameras)